# Reference type or class type variable can't accept given value

Tags: java

I want to make a binary tree but it's shame for me that I can't even insert an integer value into the tree. The problem is that I created a class `datatype` under which three properties were inserted. They are: `static datatype left`, `static datatype right`, `static int value`.

I created a class as a user defined data type:

```
public class datatype 
{
static datatype left,right;
static int value=0;
}
```

My binary tree class is:

```
datatype root,parent,node;

public int insert(int data)
{       
    node.value=data;  //using debugger found, node.value remain null even 
    node.left=null;    // after insertion of data into it.....That's my 
    node.right=null;   //  problem      
    try{
        if(root==null)
            root=node;                          
        else        
        {
            parent=root;
            insert(node);               
        }
        parent=root;
        return 1;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return 0;
    }       
}

private void insert(datatype node)
{       
    if(node.value<=parent.value)
    {
        if(parent.left==null)
        {
            parent.left=node;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            parent=parent.left;
            insert(parent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(parent.right==null)
        {
            parent.right=node;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            parent=parent.right;
            insert(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are `left` and `right` `static`? Please write `Datatype` instead of `datatype`!

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep the instance fields in `dataType` static since every single node needs its own `left`, `right` and `value`. Instance fields should never be static.

If you'd like user-defined types to be used, read up on generic types (ie. here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Also, do read up on how and why you'd use static fields: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html